# scale_y_continious divide by 1,000 and append "K"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Goal: change labels on my y axis on a bar plot from e.g. 500000 to 500K.

I want to do this inside a ggplot:

```
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {
    trans = l / 1000,
    paste0(l, "K")
    })
```

If I add either of the two commands alone, it works, i.e. I can either `trans = l / 1000` or `paste0(l, "K")` but if I try doing them both together within the same function only the last command is carried out.

I also tried this:

```
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {trans = l / 1000}) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {paste0(l, "K")})
```

This returned the notation 5e+05K not my hoped for 500K.

I cannot get both of these to work together.

How can I scale my y axis to be in thousands with a appended "K"?

Comment: typo? `{trans = l / 1000, paste0(l, "K")}` should be `{trans = l / 1000; paste0(trans, "K")}`.

Comment: Yeah that did it thank you very much. I don't understand though. In the second statement you provided `paste0(trans, "K")`, why is it not `paste0(l, "K")`?

Comment: because `l` is still its original values, it's `trans` that hold the `l / 1000` values

Comment: Ah I see. OK thank you once again